# Is it possible to get the Intent of my android Application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to get the intent for my android app in my [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) implementation. The [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class itself has no `getIntent()` just [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) seems to have this ability.

The reason for this is I have an app with several intents, which can be called stateless. But I need that the user is logged in. So I would like to check if the user is logged in and if not promt the login dialog, without hacking the same code in every activity.

Comment: lets all intents will "catched" by the same Activity - "chooser" ...in onCreate of this Activity you ll choose/start "real" Activity(with the same Intent) and finish() Activity "chooser" ... you can also put special  Extra to Intent passed from "chooser" to "real" which indicates if user is logged and make login specific stuff only in "chooser" Acticity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to have some functionality that's in every `Activity` is to make them all inherit a common superclass, something like this:

```
class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(...)) {
            doLogin();
        }
    }

class MyActivity extends LoginActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // user is now logged in
        setContentView(...);
    }
}
```

The `LoginActivity` is only there for your other activities to inherit, so don't mention it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You can't get the `Intent` in your `Application` because such a thing would make no sense. The `Application` object exists for as long as your *process* is running. At any given time there may be zero, one, or more than one of your activities live, so what `Intent` would it return?

I must admit I'm a bit puzzled about what the launching `Intent` has to do with logging in, though. It seems like you need a global object with the session state/credentials, rather than anything to do with intents.

Comment: I like the idea with inheritance. So is the logic in the common base class +1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getIntent()` of your Launcher activity

Comment: As I already said I have multiple "launchers" and I want to avoid to change every activity.